# problem with inserting a forward slash in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I got problem inserting the string "AM/PM" to my mySQL table

```
$timeFormat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['timeFormat']);

$sql="
UPDATE profiles
SET firstName = '$firstName', lastName = '$lastName', language = '$language', timeFormat = '$timeFormat'
WHERE profileId = '$profileId'
";
mysql_query($sql) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
```

There is no error, but the table is only showing AM/ ??

Edit:

When I echo the $sql I get:

```
UPDATE profiles SET firstName = 'Johan', lastName = 'Lund', language = 'English', timeFormat = 'AM/PM' WHERE profileId = '27'
```

And, yes I have searched the web in a very long time before asking this question. Probably if you have any link from Stackoverflow. I have already overlooked it.

Comment: Can you please echo your $sql and post the result?

Comment: can you show the table schema/ddl for the timeFormat field?  Are you sure you are not just overflowing the field?

Comment: How big is the timeFormat column?  It it's VARCHAR(3) or something short like that, then it's truncating your data when you try to insert.

Comment: Is the table showing "AM/" or "AM/ ??"

Comment: @The Dog: Thanks. It was Varchar(3). Maybe You should add it as answer?

Comment: in fact, it was @Doon who spotted it.

Comment: @colSharpel as long as it is answered, I good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your datatype in the database If it's Varchar(3) then MySQL is truncating your data.

Answer (score 1):

nothing wrong with this insert.
it's matter of how do you see the query result.

Comment: I just checking it in phpMyAdmin and it says AM/ ?? And I also output it in XML also showing AM/? Could you bee a little more specfic?

Comment: @Woho87 there is nowhere to be more specific. Your query is okay. A forward slash is not a special character in mysql, there is not a single problem with inserting it in the database. So, it's either displaying issue or you have your field just too short, as Doon says.

Comment: What is the datatype of your timeFormat column?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like that slash is doing some type of escape upon INSERT. I assume its being interpreted as "malicious" by your php interpreter.

Run this:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
echo "Magic quotes are enabled";
else
echo "Magic quotes are disabled";
```

Let me know the result.

Comment: @Woho87: Thanks : ) Nice solution from The Dog.

Answer (score -1):

Check your character set and collation for the table, I was able to fix this with a TEXT column if it is utf8 charset and utf8_bin collation, whereas latin1 was truncating after the forward slash.